# How to handle API calls in fragments while using navGraph?

Tags: android, navigation

I'm using Navigation component in one of project which is having bottom navigation view with three menu items(for example home,profile and about). Landing page of my app is home fragment(for example) at which one API is called(in onCreateView() method) to get user lists; its working fine but whenever user navigates to some other page like profile and come back means again API gets called in home fragment.

I referred this link - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components.git

```
class Home : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup_btn).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_to_registered)
        }
        callUserListApi()
        return view
    }

    private fun callUserListApi() {
        val client = ServiceGenerator.getApiService(requireContext()).getJsonbyWholeUrl("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonArray> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonArray>, t: Throwable) {
                println("callUserListApi onFailure ${t.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonArray>, response: Response<JsonArray>) {
                println("callUserListApi onResponse ${response.isSuccessful}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using navigation componentthe fragment were recreate every time when you select the tab. So here i've inflate fragment if my view is null when come back to those fragment at that moment view is not null so fragment should not recreate.

```
 private var homeFragment: View? = null

 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    if (view == null){
        homeFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        callUserListApi()
    }

    return view
}
```

Comment: You might also want to explain what the OP was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Navigation component, the Fragment were recreated each time the it was selected on the navigation, meaning the onCreateView() is called that includes youre callUserListApi()

Since you are using AAC, you can create a ViewModel on your activity and initialize it, then re-initializing it from the Home(Fragment). Add a MutableLiveData() variable which you can check if you alread called callUserListApi().

Dont forget to call it inside onActivityCreated()

On Home

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    mainActivityViewModel.calledUserList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {


        if(it != true) {
           callUserListApi()
        }

     })

}

private fun callUserListApi() {
      val client = ServiceGenerator.getApiService(requireContext()).getJsonbyWholeUrl("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
    client.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonArray> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonArray>, t: Throwable) {
            println("callUserListApi onFailure ${t.message}")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonArray>, response: Response<JsonArray>){
            println("callUserListApi onResponse ${response.isSuccessful}")
            mainActivityViewModel.setCalledUserList(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Inside youre MainActivityViewModel

```
val _calledUserList = MutableLiveData<Boolean?>()
val calledUserList = _calledUserList

fun setCalledUserList(bool: Boolean?) {
    _calledUserList.value = bool
}
```